# Add Buttons render differently in IE to Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

During a stay at my parents in-law (I don't use IE), I noticed that the buttons render differently in IE 10(version 10.0.9200.16466) and IE 9. See added snapshots:

**IE10** (main)

[image]

**IE9** (meta)

[image]

Should this be the case? Can somebody add the Chrome snapshot to confirm this?

**UPDATE 03-01-2012 15:05 CEST**
*IE9 (main)*
[image]

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: Version: 10.0.9200.16466

Comment: definitely a bug. Chrome doesn't have the background highlight http://i.imgur.com/DhUhZ.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is on dev server now, will be deployed to live in our next production build.

Comment: @Sathya & Jin: is there a follow-up on these things?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra there should be a production build tonight, then the change will be on the live server.

Comment: @Sathya & Jin: I've not been able to see any changes.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra it should be fixed on live now. We just built production. Can you verify the fix?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I just found out the fix I pushed didn't fix the problem! I pushed another fix, should be in the next prod build (sometimes tonight or tomorrow).

Comment: Confirmed - it is now fixed.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra as a side note, since I didn't comment on Jin's answer, I didn't get notified of your comments. In short: If a person hasn't participated(edits/comments/ask/answer) in a post, addressing them in comments won't result in the person getting notified

Comment: @Sathya it should be......haha. Can this be a feature request?